# JUCE Giving "memory.h" Not Found

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, juce

I need help with a problem in JUCE, I have like almost a year of experience with c++ so I decided to start developing a music application, I've extracted JUCE.zip to my C drive, started the JUCE app, but when I create a GUI app it doesn't seem to find all the MinGW headers, after I compile it says something along the lines of..."Cannot locate memory.h" I would appreciate an answer to this question greatly
appreciated, thx in advance.

Comment: What is your build script?  Is the `memory.h` file in the same directory as the rest of your files?  This usually happens because MinGW doesn't know where to look for your header files.  By default it only looks in a few, limited locations.  If the header isn't in a default search location, you have to specify where it is.

Comment: The header files are in the default place where Mingw installed them so that's not the problem

Comment: So your header file is in `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.2\include`? If the header isn't in the default search space, you have to manually specify where the headers are.

Comment: I'll check when I get back to my PC and see if it's in that directory.

Comment: @Major I checked and it's in the right spot...so idk I'll research the error some more to see what I come up with...c++ is so complicated sometimes smh

Comment: Could you show some of the code in your question? Specifically the `include` directives, and the command you're using to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem in question, for some reason it was my computer that was causing the problem along with code::blocks, they just didn't run together well after I got a virus a while back...so I opted out and used [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) instead and now it works perfectly, thx for the help though.